# Custom Navigation Bar height is not coming properly

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

[I have give the Navigation Bar height to 104 but navigation bar item is displaying only till height 44 ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZrQ4.png)

I cannot post code due to some reason.I am not allow to post the picture also.
My navigation bar item is not display to full height it only comes to  up to 44.

For Navigation Bar:

```
enter code here         
let nav = UINavigationbar();    
nav.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:View.frame.width,height:104)   
view.addsubview(nav)
```

Please forgive me for my poor English.

Comment: are you using navigationCcontroller ?

Comment: I am not using navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to subclass `UINavigationBar` and use that

```
class HeightedNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 104)
    }

}
```

Comment: Navigation right bar button height still at 44 even if I increased the height of the button